# Problema con estructura html para un formulario

Tags: html, bootstrap

junto con saludarlos, voy a explicar un poco el contexto.

Realicé un formulario que está hecho con bootstrap y se ve de la siguiente forma, voy a poner una foto para que se hagan la idea de cómo se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El esquema de las columnas es el siguiente:
También comentar que al form en su clase le puse **d-flex justify-content-center** para que me lo ordene así:

```html
--col-lg-12 (este es para el titulo)
--form (todo el formulario)
----col-lg-7 (columna de la izquierda)
------formulario-cl 
----col-lg-5 (columna de la derecha)
------formulario-hijo 
------formulario-hijo
```

Ahora el código del container que tiene todo:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <h1 class="titulo1">Formulario</h1>
   </div>
   <form action="" method="post" class="formulario col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">

    <div class="col-lg-7 d-flex justify-content-center">
     <div class="formulario-cl formulario-base">
      <h3>Contacto</h3>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="rut" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Rut</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rut" name="rut" placeholder="" required oninput="checkRut(this)">
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="nombres" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Nombres</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombres" name="nombres" placeholder="Nombres">
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="apellidos" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Apellidos</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" placeholder="Nombres">
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="fechanacimiento" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Fecha Nacimiento</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechanac" name="fechanacimiento" placeholder="02-02-1986">
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="celular" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Número Celular</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="celular" name="celular" placeholder="+56987768598">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
       <label for="sexo" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Sexo</label>
       <div class="col-sm-8 pad-sexo">
        
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Masculino</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Femenino</label>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="correo" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Correo</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="correo" name="celular" placeholder="nombre@algo.com">
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="direccion" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Dirección</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
           <div class="col">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Dirección">
           </div>
           <div class="col">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número">
           </div>
         </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="localidad" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Localidad</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
              <option selected>Elija...</option>
              <option value="1">Agua Fresca</option>
              <option value="2">Barrio Prat</option>
              <option value="3">Otra</option>
            </select>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="instagram" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Instagram</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="instagram" name="instagram" placeholder="instagram">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-5 d-flex flex-column">
     
     <!-- Formulario Hijo 1-->
     <div class="formulario-hijo formulario-base">
     <h4>Contacto Adicional 1</h4>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="nomad1" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Nombres</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomad1" name="nomad1" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="apellidosad1" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Apellidos</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidosad1" name="apellidosad1" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="telefonoad1" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Teléfono</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefonoad1" name="telefonoad1" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="correoad1" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Correo</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="correoad1" name="correoad1" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    
     <!-- formulario hijo 2-->
     <div class="formulario-hijo formulario-base">
      <h4>Contacto Adicional 2</h4>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="nombread2" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Nombres</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombread2" name="nombread2" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="apellidosad2" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Apellidos</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidosad2" name="apellidosad2" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="telefonoad2" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Teléfono</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefonoad2" name="telefonoad2" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="correoad2" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Correo</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="correoad2" name="correoad2" placeholder="">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Ahora!! según entiendo, si agrego otro div bajo el **col-lg-5** que sea  **col-lg-12** y dentro le pongo un botón para el submit, creo que debería quedar abajo de todo, pero no... me corre todo para la izquierda.

```html
--col-lg-12 (este es para el titulo)
--form (todo el formulario)
----col-lg-7 (columna de la izquierda)
------formulario-cl 
----col-lg-5 (columna de la derecha)
------formulario-hijo 
------formulario-hijo
----col-lg-12
-------boton
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que es algo de la propiedad de flex pero no se me ocurre cómo arreglarlo o puede que mi estructura esté mal hecha pero mi idea es que el formulario se vea así.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo quieres que el botón de guardar se ubique debajo de las dos columnas de formularios que ya tienes, te recomiendo leer un poco sobre forma en la que Bootstrap maneja su [`Grid`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/), en pocas palabras suma el valor numérico de la clase `col-lg-X` hasta un total de 12 y así sabe qué espacio darle a cada columna.

Creo que lo que buscas es una estructura de ésta forma:

```
--col-lg-12 (este es para el titulo)
--form (todo el formulario)
----col-lg-7 (columna de la izquierda)
------formulario-cl 
----col-lg-5 (columna de la derecha)
------formulario-hijo 
------formulario-hijo
--col-lg-12
-------boton
```

Modifica tu código para que el botón, sea una fila al mismo nivel que tu título y formulario.

Para enviar el formulario con tu botón externo puedes hacer esto:

Ponerle un `id` a tu form y usar la propiedad `form` dentro de tu botón para que al hacer click el botón ejecute la acción del formulario.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="miFormulario"></form>
```

```
<!-- Boton externo al form-->
<button type="submit" form="miFormulario">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, una consulta, que el botón quede fuera del form afecta en algo? o igual hace el envío de los datos?

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda edité mi respuesta con esta pregunta que me haces

Comment: gracias de nuevo